# Galvanized steel hinge screws with stainless steel hinges: What is the risk of galvanic corrosion?

Tags: screws, steel, hinges, stainless, galvanic-corrosion

The screws in question are zinc-plated hardened steel screws (1 1/4 in) for use with heavy duty fire-rated stainless steel interior door hinges of unspecified grade.

There is a theoretical risk of galvanic corrosion, given that both the zinc plating and carbon steel are anodic to stainless steel. However, I've come across a number of resources that claim that the risk of this is negligible in a typical mild-moderate-humidity urban interior environment.

[Galvanize It!: Dissimilar Metals](https://galvanizeit.org/hot-dip-galvanized-steel-bridges-online-seminar/hdg-bridge-design/dissimilar-metals)

I've seen a number of SS hinges that have BZP screws in them with no visible corrosion.

Given their relative availability, is it worth the extra effort to track down stainless steel screws for stainless steel hinges, or should I just stick to using galvanized steel screws?

Comment: If you spent the money to get stainless steel hinges, why skimp on the screws. Didn't the hinges come with the screws?

Comment: We're replacing some stripped hinge screws as part of renovation works. The SS hinges were part of the original construction. However, SS screws are a little difficult to get hold of at short notice.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you're worried about the screws, install with them and replace when you can. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Indoors? No they won't corrode. Zinc looks different than stainless which is more dull, so just get the right screws. It looks bad, I've done it before on accident.

Commercial door hardware companies will have boxes of them.